# How to log out of Gmail of all devices from desktop

Tags: gmail

I'm logged in my Gmail account all the time with my cell phone. Tonight I lost my cell phone and would like to log off on all devices. Can I do this from my home computer after I log in to my Gmail account?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, extracted from the following [Gmail help article.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?hl=en)

> **Forgot to sign out?**
>
> If you've forgotten to sign out of Gmail on another computer, you can
>   sign out of your other sessions by going to the bottom right corner of
>   Gmail, clicking **Details**, and then **Sign out all other sessions.**

Comment: It's no problem. I was just making your post a little easier on the eye.

Answer (score 1):

You could also go to [this Devices & activity page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) and remove the access for any device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Gmail app, the solution made by pnuts would't work. The only option then is to check if you have remote access via Android Device Manager (https://www.google.de/android/devicemanager) enabled, so you can delete everything that is on your phone.